# Which entity relationship method looks right or better?

Tags: entity-relationship, rdbms

I see that there are two different ways to make entity relationship on the example illustrated below (either by one to one or by many to many). Which one is better method? (What is the better method in terms of common practice or widely accepted convention. Possibly, which one is more efficient? If there is no better method what would be the trade-off of using one instead of another?)

One-to-one method
[image]

Many-to-many method
[image]

Comment: There is no 'better' in engineering unless you define it so we can evaluate it. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. PS What have you researched, eg your textbook & SO?

Comment: @philipxy I edited the scope of the question. Let me know if you need any further clarification. PS I don't know how to make effective ER diagram with plain text. I skipped the legend becaue ER diagram is commonly understood convention by many. Research is just derived from my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, neither diagram is an entity-relationship diagram. Entity-relationship diagrams should be able to represent entity-relationship concepts, but the notation you used doesn't distinguish between entity relations and relationship relations, and shows columns, types and foreign key constraints, which belong in a physical model rather than a conceptual one. What you have is better described as table diagrams. For ERDs, I recommend Chen's original notation or something close to it.

The first diagram mixes a higher-level abstraction into an otherwise physical model, and for that reason, I recommend the second style as it's more consistent.

Note that in either diagram, CompanyType_ID in General appears at odds with the type of relationship you're trying to represent. It may not necessarily be wrong (entities described in General may each have a primary or distinguished CompanyType in addition to a set of secondary types) but even if it's modeled that way intentionally, it warrants a second look at least.